# Horizontal loader when data loads

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a loader as in horizontal line. My html is :

```
<div class="animated yt-loader"></div>
```

My css is :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.yt-loader {
    -webkit-animation-name: horizontalProgressBar;
    animation-name: horizontalProgressBar;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    background: #ef534e;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
}

.yt-loader:after{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: #ef534e 1px 0 6px 1px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
@keyframes horizontalProgressBar
{
    0%   {width: 0%;}
    20%  {width: 10%;}
    30%  {width: 15%;}
    40%  {width: 18%;}
    50%  {width: 20%;}
    60%  {width: 22%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

But like this I am unable to do this with the data loading. I need to add some delay or anything else so that when after 3s or 4s when data loads the line width increases 100%.

Comment: What's the question? Where is the JS with loaded files?

Comment: you can add another CSS property like `animation-delay: 3s;` inside `.yt-loader`

Comment: I am trying to this in css only on the basis of keyframe.

Comment: @vish check my answer.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I need to add animation-delay on keyframe. Is it possible. Because the fast movement of line depends upon the data.

Comment: the `animation-delay` does add on keyframes but it just means the keyframes will start after 3s and then will continue as normal. Do you mean you need each of the keyframes (0%, 20% 30%) to have different delays ?

Answer (score 2):

sir,

You Have to change animation duration Time in `Animated` Class

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/o7p15tqt/)

Answer (score 0):

You have edit the animation-duration as 2s or 4s.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.yt-loader {
    -webkit-animation-name: horizontalProgressBar;
    animation-name: horizontalProgressBar;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    background: #ef534e;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
}

.yt-loader:after{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: #ef534e 1px 0 6px 1px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
@keyframes horizontalProgressBar
{
    0%   {width: 0%;}
    20%  {width: 10%;}
    30%  {width: 15%;}
    40%  {width: 18%;}
    50%  {width: 20%;}
    60%  {width: 22%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="animated yt-loader"></div>
```